# Event exit the application

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I create app for android. I need catch event exit the application. On the PC all work - I catch exit event. When I testing on the devise event didn't work.

What kind of event it is? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Listening to the NativeApplication's EXITING event should work...

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.EXITING, applicationExitHandler);

private function applicationExitHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace("exit")
}
```

However, the app on Android may be going into the background, and not actually exiting. To listen for this, use the DEACTIVATE event...

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, applicationDeactivateHandler);

private function applicationDeactivateHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace("background")
}
```

Likewise, listen for the ACTIVATE event when the app comes to the foreground.